# How To Convert Visual Studio 2010 project to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, version, visual-studio-2015, converters

I have a project from VS Studio 2010 that I want to work with in VS 2015. When I start this Project with VS 2015 I receive an error saying something like "compatibility-Error (Version)".

How can I successfully convert a Visual Studio 2010 project to use with Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 3):

Without you going into any more detail about the actual error. (error numbers / screenshot) it will be very hard for any of us to give a real answer. Therefore I am going to suggest you take a look at [Troubleshooting Unsuccessful Project Upgrades](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd627573(v=vs.100).aspx).

Something else to check out might be the [Porting, Migrating, and Upgrading Visual Studio Projects guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx)

One of the key things mentioned in the 2nd link I provided is:

> The following list describes support in Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2013 for projects that were created in Visual Studio 2012 or Visual Studio 2010 SP

Therefore I'd recommend upgrading the 2010 version to SP1 first. (if this is still installed that is)

One further thing to note is that if you keep the old version of Visual studio installed you can import a project which is made with an older version and **skip** the update. Visual studio 2015 will then use parts of the older version itself to open the project.

For details you can read [How to: Upgrade Visual C++ Projects to Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms185327(v=vs.100).aspx) page and the equally useful [Installing Visual Studio Versions Side-by-Side](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms246609.aspx) page.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there are issues when moving from VS 2010.Net to VS 2015.Net and may require that you build the project from scratch and copy the code over.  VS 2015 requires a Namespace.  There are a number of designer issues on control that require the style page be used since various attributes have been removed. Something still, however, do work but you need to review the HTML, specifically things like Font and alignment. While it's a pain it isn't a big deal since it requires mostly cut and paste.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues converting web projects the projects may have originally been created as a "web site" rather than a "web Project" .  Try opening the application as a web site and see what happens.  At least that may help get you to the point you can actually get to the code to convert it in VS 2015.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

Try to Right-click the solution, then select "Re-target solution".